# get Content-Length of String[]

Tags: java, arrays, http, content-length

How do i get the `Content-Length` of a `String[]` in java?

Current code:

```
public static int getLength(String[] sa) {
    int result = 0;
    for (String s : sa)
        result += s.length();
    return result;
}
```

But an incorrect value is returned therefor the browser doesn't read the whole message body.

Comment: Oh, i'm trying to implement keep-alive in my java HTTP server, wich requires a Content-Length to be specified otherwise the client wouldn't know where to stop reading the document. Using the code i wrote in my question the client doesn't receive the whole message, wich is because the Content-Length supplied by the server is incorrect, i assumed this was because `.length()` doesn't count some bytes, but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind i'm stupid, i needed to add 2 to the result for every `\n\r` (enter) in the `String[]`

Here's the final code:

```
public static int getLength(String[] sa) {
    int result = (sa.length - 1) * 2;
    for (String s : sa)
        result += s.length();
    return result;
}
```